# Can we add more than one special price in magento using price type attribute?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have product having price value defined, if I do not provide special price for that product, I want to display another price other than price and special price using some attribute.

And when user adds the product to cart that time this new price should be applied to product.

Is this possible in magento if yes, how can I implement this?

***update***:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <New_Price>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </New_Price>
    </modules>
   <global>
      <models>
            <price>
                <class>New_Price_Model</class>
            </price>            
        </models>     
        <events>
              <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                    <observers>
                         <price>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>New_Price_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>priceTocart</method>
                         </price>
                    </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>       
   </global>            
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Sigma\New\Model\Observer.php

**Observer.php**

```
class New_Price_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function priceTocart($observer)
    {
            Mage::log("hello",null,"pricelog.txt");             
            $quoteItem = $observer->getData();
            foreach($quoteItem as $cartItem)
            {                       
                echo $cartItem->getId()."<br>";
                echo $cartItem->getSpecialPrice()."<br>";
                echo $cartItem->getFinalPrice()."<br>";

                echo $cartItem->getRegularPrice()."<br>";

                echo $cartItem['regularprice']."<br>"; //This is my attribute values.I want to apply this value instead of final price.
            }           

    }
}   
?>
```

Or Is it possible to change the way how special price is calculated. If yes which file I need to override.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done relatively simply. Firstly you need to extend the product view block and add a function to check if you need to show the custom price on the product page. Alternatively create a helper function that you can pass the product object into. You can then use this function in the view.phtml template to display the custom price accordingly however you please.

If you want it show where the normal price is (i.e. replace it) you need to modify your price.phtml file to do the check and show the custom attribute as the price (price.phtml is a complex file but look at how special price is done in it).

To change the price on add to basket you simply create an event observer for the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event. You have access to the quote item here and you can perform your checks (i.e. if special price is there or not) and set a custom price for a quote item using

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $cartItem->getProductId() );    
$cartItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($product->getRegularprice());
```

Comment: I have one attribute for the product as regularprice I am providing some value there.I want this value to be used as product final price.How can I do this in observer suggested by you. I have created the observer.

Comment: Have updated my answer to reflect your variables. Not tested but the key to this is setting the Original Custom Price on the quote item object. Magento then recalculates the prices and tax settings accordingly. You need to add your checks for special price etc and set the original custom price if you need to.

Comment: Swatten I am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object

Comment: Try the updated answer. If not ensure you can get your price attribute from the product object and do some old school debugging. To test that setting the original custom price works you can simply do something like '$cartItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(999.99);'.

Comment: Your solution is working well.But I am getting the quantity added twice every time I add product to cart.

Comment: Is this the correct way $quoteItem = $observer->getData(); that I am using,today Iam not able to get Id and other data in foreach loop?

Comment: Product and quote item are two different things. Ensure you are using the correct object. $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem(). To get something from the quote item you will need to do $quoteItem->getQty() etc. If you want product attributes you need to load the product as shown above and then call $product->getPrice() etc. Your qty really shouldn't be doubling up though and without seeing all your code I don't why it would. Probably worth creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add one Special Price.
If u want to do this with another Attribute, so you have to rewrite the price Index.

But you can create "catalog product rules" and as reference use the sku of the product.