# Magento : Add Product to cart with custom price using observer

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

i have an input in product page that allows to customers to change the price : 
[image]

i followed that tutorial : http://magentotutorial.org/programmatically-add-product-cart-price-change-magento/

and this is my code : 
config.xml :

```
<events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
                <observers>
                    <customprice>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>WebDirect_CustomPrice_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>convertPricespanToInput</method>
                    </customprice>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>

            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <customprice>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>WebDirect_CustomPrice_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>applyCustomPrice</method>
                    </customprice>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>

        </events>
```

observer class :

```
<?php
class WebDirect_CustomPrice_Model_Observer
{
    const MODULE_NAME = 'WebDirect_CustomPrice';
    public function convertPricespanToInput($observer = NULL) {
        if (!$observer) {
            return;
        }
        if ('product.info.simple' == $observer->getEvent()->getBlock()->getNameInLayout()) {
            if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/'.self::MODULE_NAME)) {
                $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
                $block = new WebDirect_CustomPrice_Block_priceSpanToInput();
                $block->setPassingTransport($transport['html']);
                $block->toHtml();
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function applyCustomPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            $item = $item->getParentItem();
        }

        // Discounted 50% off
        $percentDiscount = 0.50;

        // This makes sure the discount isn't applied over and over when refreshing
        $specialPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice() - ($item->getOriginalPrice() * $percentDiscount);

        // Make sure we don't have a negative
        if ($specialPrice > 0) {
            $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
    }
}
```

that function is just for test
when i click add to cart nothing change !
is there any error in this ?

Comment: Have you first checked your observer method is actually being executed? Just put a `die('here')` in the start of the method and check that it is being called when you add a product to the cart. If so, move the die in to the special price check and change it to `die($specialPrice);` to ensure it's entering the if statement. Let us know if the method is actually being called, if it's not then try clearing your cache and check the module is enabled in admin.

Comment: @AshleySwatton yes its exexuted blank page with 0 so what to do next ?

Comment: I don't think it should be dieing with 0 if special price has been calculated and is supposed to be more than 0 :-). Comment out your calculations and do something simple like `$item->setOriginalCustomPrice(100.00);`. If that works you will need to debug your calculations and work out where it going wrong. I think your almost there :-)

Comment: @AshleySwatton that worked !!! now i wanna get the value of input in the frontend as u can see in the image up on question the name and the id of that input is "customprice" do u know how to do that ?

Comment: @AshleySwatton you seem have experience in magento developpement, could you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657041/get-a-value-of-a-custom-input-in-magento

Comment: Silly question, and please forgive me for being new to this, but is there a way to do this _without_ creating an observer?

Comment: @VinnieSaletto no because when clicking add to cart that's an event and when we talk about events there should be an observer

Comment: Have you tried to observe `sales_quote_add_item` instead? That fires after add/update cart item.