# Get a value of a custom input in magento

Tags: magento

First I've created an input in magento product view page as described bello :

[image]

and I've done a observer so it set a custom price when add to cart (checkout_cart_product_add_after event) and this is the function :

```
public function applyCustomPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            $item = $item->getParentItem();
        }

        $item->setCustomPrice(599.5);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice(599.5);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

    }
```

as u can see I've put "599.5" and that worked.
Now what I want is to get value of that input in product view page to the observer this is the input :

```
<div class="price-box">

    <span id="product-price-27" class="price">
        <input id="CP_ID" class="input-text price" type="text" onmouseout="onChangeCP(this);" value="2699.9900" style="width:auto;" name="custom_price"></input>
    </span>
    <input id="custom_price_total" type="hidden" value="2699.9900" name="custom_price_total"></input>

</div>
```

Anyone knows how to do that ?

Comment: you have to create one custom option textbox and take hidden variable to set your custom option[price] value and you can get easily hidden value in your observer using getParams()

Comment: how can i do that? @KeyurShah

Comment: First of all you have to custom option for product text-box after that take one hidden input type and on-click of addtocart you have to set text-box value to your hidden variable using JavaScript

Comment: yeah i will do that just tell me how to do that in observer :p @KeyurShah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are able success to call your observer using `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event then write below code to change price of product

```
 $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $new_price = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('pricecustom');
```

Where **pricecustom** is my hidden variable

```
        if(!is_null($new_price))
        {
            $quote_item->setCustomPrice($new_price);
            $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
            $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: @keyur could we use the same code if need to set custom product price from listing page ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy i think you can also apply on listing page because this event execute when product is added to cart checkout_cart_product_add_after

Comment: @AmitBera I am facing the same scenario, when I follow these steps custom_price and original custom price are updating properly but still cart price showing the original product price not the new one?

Comment: Can we implement same in magento 2 ?